# How do I find out Ubuntu partition using gparted?

Tags: 14.04, gparted

I have this partition on my computer. I am using Ubuntu system right now, but it is running out of memory. How can I find out which one is the Ubuntu partition below. Also, among these partitions, which one should I select to increase the space of Ubuntu. I know there is a Window partion (but not sure which one in the picture below), which I do not need anymore. How can I transfer Windows partion to Ubuntu using this gparted tool? And what is this unknown partition. I would appreciate any help. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see in your shots:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1 Windows System Reserved Partition
/dev/nvme0n1p2 Windows Partition
/dev/nvme0n1p8 Ubuntu Partition
/dev/nvme0n1p6 Ubuntu Swap Partition
/dev/nvme0n1p7 ext4 Formatted partition [not being used]
/dev/nvme0n1p5 Not sure about it
```

You have to increase `/dev/nvme0n1p8`, however you can just setup `/dev/nvme0n1p7` as your new home and move your files there or format the windows partition `/dev/nvme0n1p2` and do the same, if you don't need the data living there.

---

You have to format the partition you don't want to use anymore using a filesystem like `ext4` then set it as your home and move your files there, this is the safest option, otherwise you have to get a backup increase the size of Ubuntu partition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What worse do you think could happen if I format and move the unknown `dev/nvme0n1p5` directory?